# HTML5 video capture and streaming?

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm working on kind of an educational site, where there are teachers and students around the world (potentially). Since it's a non-profit site, and I don't have the need for it to be done tomorrow (kind of a side project of something bigger), I wanted to know the best way to figure out how to do this. I'm not a programmer by trade, I've been on the systems side of things for years, but I understand most technology and the question here is more how to gauge what to do so I can get the right resources in place.

That said... here's what I am looking at. I figure the future is HTML5, and that's probably where I'd rather spend my efforts given that it will be cross platform and without the need for plugins. It will work on mobile as well. Question is, how well does HTML5 handle input media, say desktop capture and camera, or on mobile perhaps, where I'd want to use the user's phone camera, etc.

Second question is dynamic streaming... I've read about MPEG DASH, then there are technologies like Smooth Streaming (which I think given the way Silverlight is going is going to be gone or useless), then also Apple and Flash, but if I'm doing HTML5 it doesn't benefit me. Any ideas here would be really helpful, and the more detail the better! :)

That's about it... there are free chat services out there like using the MSN Web Chat controls (how good they are, I don't know, but worldwide most people have a Hotmail/MSN account) so I can use that for chat. I don't know its limitations of course, but that's something if people know or have suggestions, then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the video tags doesn't support input media as such, all it does rather well for the moment is play video files IF the file formats is supported by the given browser (different browsers different extensions) Also I have seen out there a solution where someone stream their own webcam into the video tags but that was on Mac only and using other technologies to help out.

The video tag is not supported by all browsers either, recent modern one will but if you need to support IE flash is still a better alternative way to provide videos across all platforms.

Streaming is only partially supported by some browsers and is not an easy task to achieve.

Here is few links that might help.

http://ishtml5readyyet.com/

http://html5readiness.com/

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements

Comment: Input and output are two different things... the "admin" view would be an input -- and then there would be a "client" view that shows output. So the <video> tag only needs to work for the client, the admin view needs to have an input into a server.

The other question is dynamic streaming, and MPEG DASH. I figure even if I don't do this within a year (which I probably won't!), then MPEG DASH might come closer to reality, as well as the rest of HTML5. That's where I want the guidance for. I don't want something for TODAY, I want to build something for TOMORROW :)

Answer (score 3):

There are actually several posibilities to do this since HTML5 makes it super easy to stream most the basic input using video tags is however very much limited because you won't have actual access to the bytes like you would want.

But to convert something basic like mp4 to html5 compatible video just use this converter tool:
http://easyhtml5video.com/